# Next.js install - useContext error when initial install haven't touched any files

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

When intially installing a `npx create-next-app@latest` or `npx create-next-app@latest --typescript` complete the install and then try running with `next dev` I see a useContext error.
I haven't touched any files and am just trying to run bare bones but yet I'm seeing this error, I even search for useContext in vs code search and nothing is found.

Wondering if I'm the only one who is experiencing this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i run cmd `npx create-next-app@latest --ts` is all right,i guess y maybe at that time network is bad
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJz2k.png)

Comment: Very odd `yarn dev` throws no errors & runs but `next dev` throws the useContext error

Answer (score 0):

looks like this is still an issue when trying to run `next dev`. ```yarn dev`` works per the comment provided prior